# Kubernetes - Do I need to some additional hardening steps?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Basically I'm new to kubernetes and I'm trying to create a simple nginx + php-fpm application. I've setup the deployment config, created the pods, setup some loadbalancers, etc.. Everything's working fine and I'm controlling the cluster from Google Cloud Shell (because the cluster is created on Google Cloud Platform). I want to ask if I need to do some additional steps or if my cluster is safe and secure, for example: can someone connect to it from outside by some way, etc.. I've kept the default settings while creating the cluster and I have client certificate enabled (that's a way of authentication, right?). I just want to make sure. (should it be secure by default?)

Comment: Could you make your question a bit more specific? Right now it might help you to do a bit of research online and figure out what you want to know.

Comment: Yes, I will do some research on this, but it should be secure now too, not? (it's not like it's unsecure, right?)

Comment: You can consider using private clusters if you are worried about the node external IP's. However I am currently deploying multiple nginx, php-fpm apps on a default GKE cluster and had to complaints. I do recommend looking into your cluster design, you might want to have the connection with the external tools airtight. It would help me to assist you better if you share your infra.

Comment: Umm what do you mean by "infrastructure"?

Answer (score 2):

Consider what exactly you are "hardening" against; you can consider security from two contexts: application and cluster. They are usually decoupled, but can cause some serious problems if either gets compromised.

For **cluster security**, there are many options on GKE to restrict access to your cluster that covers the majority of use-cases. You can use [RBAC](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/role-based-access-control) (Role-based access control) to limit user and service account permissions and prevent unauthorized access/modification to your cluster resources. Additionally, if you use external tool (eg. Helm), you will need to secure these individually. By default, only those with the client certificate should be able to access your master. If you share the certificate, or if another user in your Google Organizations account has the [IAM](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#kubernetes-engine-roles) permissions to access your cluster, they could also grab permissions from the Google Cloud CLI. A good cluster security enforcement can greatly mitigate the effects of a compromised container/pod.

For **application security**, follow the best practices for deploying containerized applications and secret management. Basically secure your nginx and php as you would on traditional servers.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm hardening against "cluster security", so if I keep the cluster like this and make sure I  hide the certificate from anyone and someone gets the IP addresses of the clusters (in the outside internet) it should be secure, and no one can connect to it unless I share the client certificate or someone gets into my Google Cloud Platform account, do I understand it correctly? By connecting to the cluster I mean someone connecting to it for example using kubectl and controlling something..

Comment: For a GKE cluster, it should be sufficiently robust for what you hope to accomplish; just be careful when using external tools like Helm/Tiller. Your understanding is correct.

Comment: Yes I don't use any external tools.